# Django autoescaping, ignoring autoescape off and |safe

Tags: django, templates, filter, escaping

I've got a Django filter that's not doing the right thing.  I'm expecting to see actual html in the output, but what I see are html escaped brackets.  I've tried autoescape off, and I've tried |safe, and I've tried both at the same time.  No joy.  Wtf?

```
<td>{% autoescape off %}{{ notif.output|safe|insert_breaks|linkify }}{% endautoescape %}</td>
```

I'm not seeing any errors, just autoescaped text that really shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Maybe some more information (code) of your custom template filters?

Comment: insert_breaks is really as simple as text = text.replace('\n', ' <br> ')...  Yet, I'm seeing ampersand gt; and ampersand lt; in the output.

Comment: Can you try adding `|safe` after all the other filters (`insert_breaks` and `linkify`)? As far as I know filters are chained. From the Django docs: "If you are chaining filters, a filter applied after safe can make the contents unsafe again.".

Comment: I tried safe at the end as well.  It was a configuration issue, due to having multiple instances on the same host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to this is:

Make sure your template_dir in settings.py is pointing to the correct instance, when running multiple versions of your code on one host.

Comment: Interesting speculation. I've only seen it happen once in 4 years, but it was a b*tch to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just read the docs again. The answer is that having any [filters *after* your `safe` makes the string unsafe again](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#safe). So either put `safe` at the end, or put it at the end *again*.